# What does it mean to declare a 'local' variable inside a 'let'?

Tags: cairo-lang, starknet

As I understand it, `let` defines a reference, which can be seen as an alias, so for example `let x = y * y * y` doesn't compute `y * y * y` but the occurrences of `x` will be replaced by `y * y * y`.
Local variables are similar to other languages local variables.

As in https://www.cairo-lang.org/docs/hello_cairo/dict.html, what does it mean to write `let (local dict_start : DictAccess*) = alloc()`? That every instance of `local dict_start : DictAccess*` will be replaced by `alloc()`? Why not just `local (dict_start : DictAccess*) = alloc()` or `let (dict_start : DictAccess*) = alloc()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that when a function is called, the returned values are placed in memory, so e.g. in the case of `alloc` which returns a single value, the return value can be found in `[ap-1]` (you can read more about the stack structure and function calls [here](https://starknet.io/docs/how_cairo_works/functions.html#functions)).

`let (dict_start : DictAccess*) = alloc()` is actually valid, and is a syntactic sugar for the following:

```
alloc()
let dict_start = [ap-1]
```

`let (local dict_start : DictAccess*) = alloc()` is equivalent to:

```
alloc()
let dict_start = [ap-1]
local dict_start = dict_start
```

In the last line, I substitute the value referenced by `dict_start` value into a local variable, and rebind the reference `dict_start` to the location of the local variable. The motivation to use this might be to avoid potential revocations (which may be solved by putting the return value in a local variable). This is probably what you want to do with `local (dict_start : DictAccess*) = alloc()`, which is simply not supported by the current version of the compiler.